# Why does adding this line to a Select slow down SQL drastically?

Tags: oracle11g

I have a fairly complicated query that uses a bunch of tables. It usually takes ~17 seconds to return all records (though it is usually filtered).  One of the fields it returns is `CAT.OLD_CODE`.  When I replace that field with `NVL(CAT.OLD_CODE,(CASE WHEN ISS.WHDEF_CODE = 'SCRAP' THEN 'SCRAP' ELSE 'QH/PH/CUST' END))` the query takes forever (I haven't let sql developer run it long enough to get just the first 50 rows yet).  `ISS.WHDEF_CODE` is already in the select statement, and both `CAT` and `ISS` are outer joined to the main body of the query.  I'm using the command in a crystal report, and currently doing the filtering there, but I'm just curious why the `CASE` statement takes so long (just using `NVL` has no appreciable impact on performance).  I've noticed this before when using string operations in select statements, but this seems to just be a simple comparison.

Comment: Please show an *actual* query SSCCE - with performance plans. When using expression in place of a column drastically slows down the query it generally means the query has become un-SARGABLE. (But I'm not about to read a brick wall or to guess how these inner and outer queries relate or what index selection there may or may not be.)

Comment: explain plan pls, for both queries and row counts for the tables, maybe indexes too